# Django Custom File Storage system

Tags: python, django

I have a custom storage

```
import os
from django.core.files.storage import Storage


class AlwaysOverwriteFileSystemStorage(Storage):
    def get_available_name(self, name):
        """
        Directly Returns a filename that's 
        from what user input.
        """
        if self.exists(name):
    # Remove the existing file
        os.remove(name)
    # Return the input name as output
        return name
```

I want to know where should I put his `AlwaysOverwriteFileSystemStorage.py` file and how should by **settings.py** define `DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE`

My Django root folder is **/home/username/webapp**

When I put `DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'site.storage.AlwaysOverwriteFileSystemStorage'`, it returns an

**Error**

> Error importing storage module site.storage: "No module named storage"

I am not familiar with Python/Django, any help will be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Based on your path, it seems that your project is called "site" and there's a directory inside called "storage." Make sure there's a blank __init__.py file inside "storage."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can put it anywhere, but you should point the path to there in the settings.py

You can put this `storage.py` file in the root folder (the one that has `manage.py`) and point the path as `storage.AlwaysOverwriteFileSystemStorage`

Comment: This should be the correct accepted answer, as it solves the problem and not bypasses it.

Answer (score 24):

You don't need to put anything in your `settings.py`.  Just use it directly in your model.  For example, create `storage.py` wherever your app is located and put `OverwriteStorage()` in it.  Then, your model could look like this:

```
from storage import OverwriteStorage
...
class MyModel(models.Model):
    ...
    image = ImageField(upload_to='images', storage=OverwriteStorage())
```

I am also using a custom storage system to overwrite existing files.  My `storage.py` looks like this:

```
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage

class OverwriteStorage(FileSystemStorage):
    """
    Returns same name for existing file and deletes existing file on save.
    """                                                              
    def _save(self, name, content):
        if self.exists(name):
            self.delete(name)
        return super(OverwriteStorage, self)._save(name, content)

    def get_available_name(self, name):
        return name
```

Answer (score 1):

I try to make this, but don`t work for me, until I make this on my storage.py :

```
import os
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage


class MyFileSystemStorage(FileSystemStorage):
    def get_available_name(self, name, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.exists(name):
            os.remove(os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, name))
        return super().get_available_name(name, *args, **kwargs)
```

No other changes was required.

Another way yo do this:

```
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage

class AvatarStorage(FileSystemStorage):

    def get_available_name(self, name, *args, **kwargs):
        self.delete(name)
        return super().get_available_name(name, *args, **kwargs)
```

The delete method check if the file exists. So these 3 line are enough.
I hope this help somebody