# ImageField overwrite image file with same name

Tags: django, django-models

I have model `UserProfile` with field `avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_avatar)`

`upload_avatar` function names image file according `user.id` (12.png for example).

But when user updates the avatar, new avatar name coincide with old avatar name and Django adds suffix to file name (12-1.png for example).

There are way to **overwrite file instead of create new file**?

Comment: You can add date time to your actual image .. You could use it as suffix .. like '2016_987890_image.jpg' .. this will help you in serching image too

Comment: This is simple with a full code example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4905384/585783

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Yeah, this has come up for me, too. Here's what I've done.

Model:

```
from app.storage import OverwriteStorage

class Thing(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(max_length=SOME_CONST, storage=OverwriteStorage(), upload_to=image_path)
```

Also defined in models.py:

```
def image_path(instance, filename):
    return os.path.join('some_dir', str(instance.some_identifier), 'filename.ext')
```

In a separate file, storage.py:

```
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage
from django.conf import settings
import os

class OverwriteStorage(FileSystemStorage):

    def get_available_name(self, name):
        """Returns a filename that's free on the target storage system, and
        available for new content to be written to.

        Found at http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/976/

        This file storage solves overwrite on upload problem. Another
        proposed solution was to override the save method on the model
        like so (from https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/11663):

        def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
            try:
                this = MyModelName.objects.get(id=self.id)
                if this.MyImageFieldName != self.MyImageFieldName:
                    this.MyImageFieldName.delete()
            except: pass
            super(MyModelName, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        """
        # If the filename already exists, remove it as if it was a true file system
        if self.exists(name):
            os.remove(os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, name))
        return name
```

Obviously, these are sample values here, but overall this works well for me and this should be pretty straightforward to modify as necessary.

Comment: Thanks, there are what I need. Maybe you know how to delete image file, when user clears up their avatar?

Comment: I'm not sure about what you mean by "clears up their avatar," but the os.remove(filename) should delete anything you need deleted. Or are you asking something else?

Comment: I mean "clear the avatar" checkbox, generated by `forms.ImageField` in forms.

Comment: Why do you need explicitly `os.remove` the file before returning? I.e. why not simply `return name` and have the filesystem overwrite the existing file, if it exists?

Comment: @Marco by default django will not overwrite a file if it exists. However, a better way to do it is to use `self.delete`, with it you don't need the `self.exists` check and it ignores the error raised if the file is deleted (by another thread or process) between checking for existence and actual deletion.

Comment: In my opinion, you should override _save for the file deletion, as mentioned below in the answer of user2732686

Comment: This answer is seriously flawed. What if the storage was configured to store files in a different directory than `MEDIA_ROOT`? You could even delete a completely different file. As others pointed out, it's better to use `self.delete(name)`. Since it's marked as the correct answer, it would be better if it was corrected, since it will be copy-pasted a lot.

Comment: This is still useful till now. Anyone who implements this from Django 2.1 should add max_length=None. Thus <code>def get_available_name(self, name, max_length=None)<code>

Comment: I had to add the max_length parameter as well

`def get_available_name(self, name, max_length=100):`

Comment: error  get_available_name() got an unexpected keyword argument 'max_length'

Answer (score 29):

```
class OverwriteStorage(get_storage_class()):
    
    def _save(self, name, content):
        self.delete(name)
        return super(OverwriteStorage, self)._save(name, content)

    def get_available_name(self, name, max_length=None):
        return name
```

Comment: Why don't you upvote this answer? In my opinion, it's way better to override _save for the file deletion than expecting get_available_name to get just called once before the save method... It can lead to bugs if you use it somewhere else in the code for some reason...

Comment: @Kukosk This answer hasn't more upvotes mostly because it's 3 years late and maybe because it lacks a description.

Comment: FWIW I'd rather not overwrite internal methods of a parent class. In the event _save() is removed or has its args changed this code will break and the change won't be mentioned in the release notes since it isn't part of the public API.

Comment: Be wary of this solution. A race condition where 2 processes save the same file at the same time can trigger an infinite loop in the base class  `FileSystemStorage._save()`. If the file exists when the base class's `_save()` method is called, it will catch the resulting `EEXIST` exception and will try again after calling `get_available_name()`. However, because `get_available_name()` has been overridden above to not modify the filename, the `EEXIST` exception will happen again. That sequence is repeated infinitely.

Comment: @WillKeeling You are completely right. How would you avoid it?

Comment: @Coderji I ended up using this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/19961911/2091925 which ensures that the original file is deleted in `get_available_name()`

Answer (score 27):

You can write storage class even better this way:

```
class OverwriteStorage(FileSystemStorage):

    def get_available_name(self, name, max_length=None):
        self.delete(name)
        return name
```

Basically this will overwrite the function `get_available_name` to delete the file if already exists and return the name of the file already storaged

Comment: `self.delete` will check if the file exists, therefore the `self.exists` check is not necessary.

Comment: returning `super().get_available_name(name, max_length)` at the end will allow the filename shortening algorithm to work, in cases where `name` is longer than `max_length`.

Answer (score 13):

Just refference your model image field, delete it and save again.

```
model.image.delete()
model.image.save()
```

Comment: This solution saves me tons of time. You deserve a thumb.

Comment: Simple and Straightforward

Answer (score 12):

ahem... it may sound unorthodox, but my solution, at present, is to check&remove the existing file within the callback I already use for providing the name of the uploaded file. In models.py:

```
import os
from django.conf import settings

def avatar_file_name(instance, filename):
    imgname = 'whatever.xyz'
    fullname = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, imgname)
    if os.path.exists(fullname):
        os.remove(fullname)
    return imgname
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to=avatar_file_name,
                                default=IMGNOPIC, verbose_name='avatar')
```

Comment: This works for me. This solution is simple and straightforward. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to

Answer (score 8):

For Django 1.10 I found I had to modify the top answer to include the max_length argument in the Function:

```
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage
import os

class OverwriteStorage(FileSystemStorage):
def get_available_name(self, name, max_length=None):
    if self.exists(name):
        os.remove(os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, name))
    return name
```

Answer (score 6):

You can try to define your own Filesystemstorage and override the default get_availbale_name method.

```
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage 
import os

class MyFileSystemStorage(FileSystemStorage):
    def get_available_name(self, name):
        if os.path.exists(self.path(name)):
            os.remove(self.path(name))
        return name
```

For your image you could define a fs like this:

```
fs = MyFileSystemStorage(base_url='/your/url/', 
     location='/var/www/vhosts/domain/file/path/')
avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_avatar, storage=fs)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the solutions mentioned here. But it seem not to work at django 1.10. It would raise the following error somewhere at the admin's template:

`url() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name'`

So I came up with my own solution, which consists on creating a pre_save signal that tries to get the instance from the database before it's saved and remove it's file path:

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save


@receiver(pre_save, sender=Attachment)
def attachment_file_update(sender, **kwargs):
    attachment = kwargs['instance']
    # As it was not yet saved, we get the instance from DB with 
    # the old file name to delete it. Which won't happen if it's a new instance
    if attachment.id:
        attachment = Attachment.objects.get(pk=attachment.id)
        storage, path = attachment.its_file.storage, attachment.its_file.path
        storage.delete(path)
```

Answer (score 0):

in Django 4.2 You can try to define your own Filesystemstorage and override the default exists method.

```
class OverwriteStorage(FileSystemStorage):
    def exists(self, name):
        exists = os.path.lexists(self.path(name))
        if exists:
            os.remove(os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, name))
        return exists
```

and define your model with a new filesystem class

```
class IMGUpload(TimeStampMixin):
    file = models.FileField(blank=False, null=False,
                            storage=OverwriteStorage(),
                            upload_to=get_uploaded_file_path,
                            validators=[validate_file_extension])
```