# How can I save image from MS AD, into the field of django model?

Tags: python, django

I tried ContentFile and save() method from FieldFile in views.py, but in the model I'm using ImageField. It even works. But the Image saving with strange id like NameOfImage_gdicbHhvd.jpg. How can I save it normally?

Comment: It has added `_gdicbHhvd` to give it a unique filename because you already have `NameOfImage.jpg` saved in the directory you're saving the files

Comment: @HenryM But if I want overwrite file?

Comment: Try this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9522759/imagefield-overwrite-image-file-with-same-name