# Python Django does not overwrite newly uploaded file with old one

Tags: python, django, django-views

I want to overwrite/replace a file whenever a new file is uploaded. Currently the app can upload the file to a specific folder but its not overwriting files in an event that a new file has been uploaded. I need assistance to resolve that.

views.py

```
def uploadfunc(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        form =uploadfileform(request.POST,request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return render_to_response('upload_successful.html')
    else:
        form=uploadfileform()
    return render(request, 'upload.html',{'form':form})
```

models.py

```
class uploadfolder(models.Model):
    """ my application """
    File_to_upload = models.FileField(upload_to='')
```

forms.py

```
class uploadfileform(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=uploadfolder
        fields=('File_to_upload',)
```

Comment: do you just need to have just one uploaded file in your project?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImageField overwrite image file with same name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9522759/imagefield-overwrite-image-file-with-same-name)

Comment: please read a little [django codestyle](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/internals/contributing/writing-code/coding-style/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this using Django pre_save signal, which will delete the file before saving if exists.

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
import os

#It will activate whenever you will save file in uploadfolder model
@receiver(pre_save, sender=uploadfolder)
def file_update(sender, **kwargs):
    upload_folder_instance = kwargs['instance']
    if upload_folder_instance.id:
        path = upload_folder_instance.file_to_upload.path
        os.remove(path)
```

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks @vermanil my update models.py that works for me.

```html
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
import os

class uploadfolder(models.Model):
    """ my application """
    File_to_upload = models.FileField(upload_to='')

@receiver(pre_save, sender=uploadfolder)
def file_update(sender, **kwargs):
    upload_folder_instance = kwargs['instance']
    if upload_folder_instance.File_to_upload:
        path = upload_folder_instance.File_to_upload.path
        os.remove(path)
```