# Django add some weird characters at the end of the file

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have probelem when I submit the file to the django server and the name of the file exist in a directory. Django do not override the file, but it add some characters to the end of the name. How can I add characters instead of Django.

My model.py looks like this

```
class UpLoadFile(models.Model):
      user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
      file = models.FileField()
      uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

      def __str__(self):
          return self.file.name + ' (' + self.user.username + ')'
```

views.py looks like this:

```
@login_required
def home(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':

        if 'upload_file' in request.POST:
            form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
            form.instance.user = request.user
            if form.is_valid():
                messages.success(request, 'Datoteka {} je bila uspešno dodana'.format(str(request.FILES["file"])))
                form.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/')

        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Datoteke {} ni bilo mogoče dodati. Preveriti če datoteka vsebuje podatke.'
                           .format(str(request.FILES["file"])))
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')


    elif request.method == 'GET':
        upload_file = UploadFileForm()
        return render(request, 'update_file/home.html', {'page_title': 'Home', 'upload_form': upload_file})
```

forms.py looks like this:

```
class UploadFileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    file = forms.FileField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = UpLoadFile
        fields = ('file',)
```

Comment: Take a look at [file storages](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/files/storage/) in django, and e.g. this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9522759/imagefield-overwrite-image-file-with-same-name).

Comment: So if a file already exists, you want to keep that file (don't overwrite) and append your own set of characters to the name of the uploaded file?

Comment: @WillKeeling Yes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default behaviour of Django's `Storage` class is to append a series of random characters to the end of the filename when the filename already exists. If you wish to control what characters are appended, you can create your own `Storage` sub-class and override the `get_available_name()` function.

A very simple example which appends a fixed set of characters to the end of the name (you might want to adapt to vary the characters):

```py
import os
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage

class MyStorage(FileSystemStorage):

    def get_available_name(self, name, max_length=None):
        if self.exists(name):
            dir_name, file_name = os.path.split(name)
            file_root, file_ext = os.path.splitext(file_name)            

            my_chars = 'abcde'  # The characters you want to append

            name = os.path.join(dir_name, '{}_{}{}'.format(file_root, my_chars, file_ext))
        return name
```

You can then specify the custom storage class on the model:

```
class UpLoadFile(models.Model):
      user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
      file = models.FileField(storage=MyStorage())  # Your custom storage
      ...
```

Also worth looking at the existing code for Django's [`get_available_name()`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/25e724a5d6e331d2d73050d6dcdf2e8593c3aebf/django/core/files/storage.py#L63).